# Need help jQuery search filter customize

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I created a search list filter with jQuery. I need some help to customize it.

I have 3 separate div's, and inside div's I have  list elements for Search results.

I want to hide other's div if search result doesn't match from the div. Check screenshot below  -

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px5u5.png)

Here is the full example code -
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGxrGR

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.navList > li').show();
  } else {
    $('.navList > li').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">


  <div class="col-lg-12 ">
    <input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col col-1">

    <h2> My List 1 </h2>

    <ul class="navList ">
      <li>special</li>
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>
      <li>acai</li>
      <li>blueberry</li>
      <li>bananas</li>
      <li>cherry</li>
      <li>coconut</li>
      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="navList ">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>
      <li>acai</li>
      <li>blueberry</li>
      <li>bananas</li>
      <li>cherry</li>
      <li>coconut</li>
      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="navList ">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>
      <li>acai</li>
      <li>blueberry</li>
      <li>bananas</li>
      <li>cherry</li>
      <li>coconut</li>
      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both"></div>


  <div class="col-lg-12 col col2">

    <h2> My List 2 </h2>

    <ul class="navList">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>
      <li>acai</li>
      <li>blueberry</li>
 
      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="navList">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>
      <li>acai</li>
      <li>blueberry</li>

      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="navList">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>
      <li>acai</li>
  
      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>

  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col col3">

    <h2> My List 3 </h2>

    <ul class="navList">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>

      <li>cherry</li>
      <li>coconut</li>
      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="navList">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>
      <li>acai</li>
   
      <li>coconut</li>
      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="navList">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>apricots</li>

      <li>cherry</li>
      <li>coconut</li>
      <li>donut</li>
      <li>durean</li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share your sample code you developed?

Comment: please check above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fiddle. Iterating over every collection of list and checking if any list item is visible in that list or not. Based on that we can hide and show particular section.

```
     $(".myList").each(function(){
       var anyResult = false;
       $(this).find('.navList li').each(function(){
            if ( $(this).is(":visible") ) {
              anyResult = true;
              return;
            }
        });
       if(!anyResult) {
         $(this).hide();
       }
     });
```

Added `myList` as class of Parent of unordered list

https://jsfiddle.net/qzszsg4s/

Updated Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qzszsg4s/1/

Comment: One issue i found. If you search "specialzzz" nothing found, its ok but when you delete "zzz" keyword from search filed the search is not working until you rewrite the whole word from the beginning.

Comment: @XIAN I have updated the fiddle. Please check - https://jsfiddle.net/qzszsg4s/1/ Happy to help further :)